# Is there something like Retr0bright but already made and trustworthy?

Tags: hardware, maintenance

I have long wanted to clean up some old hardware to make it look new again. It really bothers me that it's all yellowed and depressing-looking.

However, https://retr0bright.com/ wants me to purchase ingredients which cannot be obtained where I live, and mix it together myself. Even if it were possible, it would be such a hassle and I don't need huge amounts, but only a small amount of finished "Retr0bright".

They strongly advice against buying such "kits" on the website, but even such kits don't seem to be available to order.

Surely there must be an actual product which can be ordered in a small amount for a reasonable price for those of us who aren't hardcore chemists?

Comment: Chemical solutions which are able to bleach plastics as effectively as Retr0bright does require by their nature more care in their handling than would many household cleaning products.  Further, such solutions once prepared will have a limited shelf life.

Comment: I really don't think the approach "I want to be able to buy something ready" and retro computing fit very well together.

Answer (score 14):

The 8-Bit Guy gets good results from using 40 Volume Developer (essentially 12% peroxide, either as a cream or liquid) from the beauty salon and it's apparently available in jurisdictions where you otherwise wouldn't be able to get stronger peroxides.

However, if you're concerned about cost, I'd watch the videos in [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25521/definitive-guide-to-retrobright/25522) I posted, which go into detail on DOs, DON'Ts, how the process works, alternative methods and materials, etc.

(Including using "sunbriting", which is basically the centuries-old technique of sun-bleaching by leaving the yellowed thing out in direct sunlight. The premise being that it takes orders of magnitude longer than that to appreciably damage the plastic and, if sunbriting destroys your item, it was teetering on the edge already and *any* whitening process would have destroyed it.)

If you go with the 40 Volume Developer and use the cream rather than immersion in a tub of liquid, the #1 caution they give is to re-spread it frequently to prevent marbling from variations in the cream's thickness causing variations in the amount of light which reaches the plastic.

Comment: Amusingly, his video where he performs experiments with various retrobriting methods <https://youtu.be/qZYbchvSUDY?t=13m4s> mistakenly calls it ‘40%’ hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: Someone copying a vague recipe using imprecisely specified household/professional chemical products could go hilariously, disappointingly, malodorously, catastrophically, harmfully or fatally wrong, especially since there is a chance these ready made products are not equally formulated across jurisdictions.... Especially anything supposed to contain reagents that mean business, and might go to business with some constituent that unexpectedly ends up in the resulting mixture...

Comment: @rackandboneman Which *is* a caution that's raised in one of the videos I linked.